# Configure sudo to ask for root password

Tags: password, sudo, root, su, capistrano

Is it possibile to configure sudo to ask for root password instead of user password?

The server is configured with a root user and a simple user (let's call him simple) with limited privileges, used to deploy all the applications hosted on the server.
The user simple is not in the sudoers list thus

```
$ sudo command
```

won't work because simple's password can't grant him root privileges.

Occasionally I need to run some scripts which need root access via Capistrano (a ruby deployment tool) and it's quite difficult to code a script in order to login as root, run the script, then logout.
I'd like to be able to execute the following statement

```
$ sudo god restart tasks-group
```

and have Capistrano to prompt me for root password.
Currently, Capistrano prompts for deployment user password which is, obviously, a non admin account.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're trying to make sudo work in a way that it is not ment to - you don't want to add the 'simple' user to the sudoers file (please correct me if i'm wrong).

In that case sudo isn't the tool you want to use you want to issue `su -c <command>` this will prompt for the root password, execute the command, then exit.

Answer (score 4):

There's a flag to be set in the sudoers file if you want the user to authenticate via his own password, or via root's. The flag is called `rootpw`. Sudo is a very powerfull package, be sure to check the man page about sudoers(5).

Comment: See also information in `man sudoers` regarding `targetpw` and Runas.

Answer (score 3):

No. Use `su` to become root using the root password.

The better solution is probably to have capistrano use `sudo` on the deployment machine for tasks that need root access.

Comment: This requires the user to be included in the sudoers list. I wanted to avoid this configuration because the user can login from ssh.

Comment: But on the other hand you can add just the relevant commands to sudoers, thus limiting what the non-admin user can do. I think that this, on the whole, is more secure than involving the actual root password.

Answer (score 0):

If the deployment user is allowed to sudo, then at that point it does become a privileged account that can act in an administrative fashion.  That's the purpose of sudo.  Or am I misreading the question?

Comment: This is the point. The deployment user is not in the sudoers list.

Comment: Ok.  You might want to edit that into your question, then.  Sorry, was't clear (at least to me).

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the misunderstanding.